# BeautifulSoup scraping alternate divs

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a file I have written as a learning experiment. It looks like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="date">1st</div>
    <div class="events">
        <div class="meeting">
            <span class="name">Bob</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="date">2nd</div>
    <div class="event">
        <div class="meeting">
            <span class="name">Emma</span>
            <span class="name">Frank</span>
            <span class="name">Charlie</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="date">3rd</div>
    <div class="event">
        <div class="meeting">
            <span class="name">Lisa</span>
            <span class="name">Tony</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to scrape the data so it returns the Span with the associated Date. So for example:

```
data = [['1st', 'bob'], ['2nd', 'Emma', 'Frank' 'Charlie'], ['3rd', 'Lisa', 'Tony']]
```

The problem I am having is where the Div's `date` and `event` are on the same level, when I scrape through using the following:

```
for data in schedule_soup.find_all('div', 'container'):
    for date in data.find_all('div', 'date'):
        print(date)
    for name in data.find_all('span', 'name'):
        print(name)
```

I get this:

```
<div class="date">1st</div>
<div class="date">2nd</div>
<div class="date">3rd</div>
<span class="name">Bob</span>
<span class="name">Emma</span>
<span class="name">Frank</span>
<span class="name">Charlie</span>
<span class="name">Lisa</span>
<span class="name">Tony</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the below code, it worked for me

```
final_list=[]
dates = soup.find_all('div', 'date')
for c in range(len(dates)):
    temp_list=[]
    temp_list.append(dates[c].text)
    meeting = soup.find_all('div', 'meeting')
    meeting = BeautifulSoup(str(meeting[c]),'html.parser')
    for name in meeting.find_all('span','name'):
        temp_list.append(name.text)
    final_list.append(temp_list)
print(final_list)
```

#### Output

> [['1st', 'Bob'], ['2nd', 'Emma', 'Frank', 'Charlie'], ['3rd', 'Lisa', 'Tony']]

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you so much, it had been frustrating me on and off for a few days because I knew it was just a logic puzzle. :D

Answer (score 0):

you can use zip function:

```
final_list=[]
dates = soup.find_all('div', 'date')
meetings = soup.find_all('div', 'meeting')
for date1, meeting in zip(dates, meetings):
    temp_list=[]
    temp_list.append(date1.text)
    [temp_list.append(x.text) for x in meeting.find_all('span')]
    final_list.append(temp_list)
print (final_list)
```